# finding all the possible routes in a NxN grid

Tags: java

I have seen many solutions to the problem of robot on the grid. However all the solutions discuss the situation where the robot can only go to the right and down from its start (top left) to the destination (bottom right).

But what if the robot can go also to left and up?

An explanation would be really appreciated to help me understand.

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ to solve this? This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I did not ask for code, I just asked for suggestion

Comment: Such a task is impossible. There an infinite number of solutions, as the robot can go around a loop any number of times before reaching the end.

Comment: @ppperry _without passing the same spot twice_. No cycles.

Comment: *Short answer:* Recursion. *Medium answer:* Leave trail of where been, and remove when backtracking (returning from recursion). *Long answer:* Attempt to write some code yourself, and come back and ask **specific** question if you get stuck!!

Comment: This is a pretty simple task :) Google for 'recursion'

Comment: @user3218743 it's actually not as simple as just a recursion

Comment: @secret are you familiar with DFS?

Comment: @user3218743 yes the concept

Comment: @secret Consider your cell map as a graph where each cell is a node and edges are the connections to to neighbors. Then if you want to count number of possible ways from there run a DFS on the starting cell, if you want to calculate the shortest path with weights you can run Dijkstra or A*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to remember the spots you've visited, and let the robot go in every direction besides the ones which will bring it to spots in which it's already been.